# How to get the values inside a nested JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone let me know how can I access the values inside the `option_value` array? It's an array within another array.

I get the below error with my code:

> TypeError: json.option[i].option_value[j] is undefined

My code

```
$(document).on("click", "[name^='option']", function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var parent_id = $(this)
    .attr("name")
    .replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");

  $.ajax({
    url:
      "index.php?route=controlller/get_options&parent_id=" +
      parent_id +
      "&value=" +
      value +
      "&product_id=<?php echo $product_id; ?>",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (json) {
      if (json["option"]) {
        for (i = 0; i < json["option"].length; i++) {
          if (
            json["option"][i]["type"] == "radio" ||
            json["option"][i]["type"] == "checkbox"
          ) {
            $("#ioption" + json["option"][i]["product_option_id"])
              .find("input")
              .prop("checked", false);

            for (j = 0; j <= json["option"][i]["option_value"].length; j++) {
              $("#ioption" + json["option"][i]["product_option_id"])
                .find(
                  "input[value='" +
                    json["option"][i]["option_value"][j][
                      "product_option_value_id"
                    ] +
                    "']"
                )
                .parent()
                .show();
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    },
  });
});
```

Below is my JSON result:

```
{
  "option": [
    {
      "product_option_id": "975",
      "option_id": "76",
      "name": "Stage",
      "type": "image",
      "option_value": [
        {
          "product_option_value_id": "2490",
          "option_value_id": "389",
          "name": "Level 1",
          "price": "\u20ac  2,00"
        },
        {
          "product_option_value_id": "2491",
          "option_value_id": "390",
          "name": "Level 2",
          "price": "\u20ac  3,00"
        }
      ],
      "required": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `for (j = 0; j <= json['option'][i]['option_value'].length; j++) {` strict lower here `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an exact structure of your html, but atleast i can provide a clean solution with some [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) usage.

You can loop through each object and then you can target HTML element you want to.

**Example**

```js
result.option.map(opt => {
  if (opt.type === 'radio' || opt.type === 'checkbox') {
    let optionElement = '#ioption' + opt.option_id;
    $(optionElement).find('input').prop('checked', false);
    opt.option_value.map(optVal => {
      let inputElement = 'input[value=\'' + optVal.product_option_value_id + '\']';
      $(optionIdElement).find(inputElement).parent().show();
    });

  }
});
```

P.S: Snippet won't run as i've not included result json in the answer!

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Get value of option_value use this **option[0]["option_value"][0]** 
I just give answer according to display the top json. 
And 0 replace using any loop(for / foreach) accoding to your requirment.